# How to prove P^Q -||- ¬(¬Pv¬Q)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How do you prove P^Q -||- ¬(¬Pv¬Q)?

I would appreciate any help or tips so that I can be able to solve it!

What I'm sure of is the following:

```
P^Q                     Hyp
P                       ^I1
Q                       ^I2
¬Pv¬Q                   ass
.
.
.
¬Pv¬Q => ¬              (=>I)
¬Pv¬Q =>                (=>I)
¬(¬Pv¬Q)                (¬I)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first direction you have almost got it. You just Have to show a contradiction and that is it.

1. $P\land Q$ (premise)
2. $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ (assumption)
3. $P$ (from 1, &out)
4. $\lnot \lnot P$ (from 3, double $\lnot$in)
5. $\lnot Q$ (from 2,3, $\lor$out)
6. $Q$ (from 1, &out)
7. $Q\land \lnot Q$ (from 5, 6, &in)
8. $\bot$ (from7, contradiction in)

Therefore, $P\land Q \vdash ¬(¬Pv¬Q)$

This is for the other direction:

1. $\lnot(\lnot P \lor  \lnot Q)$ (premise)
2. $\lnot (P\land Q)$ (Assumption)
3. $P\land Q$ (from 1, $\lnot \lor$out)
4. $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ (from 2, $\lnot$&out)
5. $P$ (from 3, &out)

Contnuing from 5 hopefully you can show a contradiction.

Comment: That $\lnot\lor$out rule is *exactly what you are trying to prove*.  Please don't use deMorgan's Laws to prove a deMorgan's Law.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I have not yet learned how to prove with contradiction i.e. what we need to make use of are either conjunction Intro and Elimination, disjunction Intro and Elimination, implication Intro and Elimination, bi implication Intro and Elimination, negation Intro and Elimination.
Is there a way this can be solved like this?

Comment: @DavidVella You are welcome. I see,  I am sorry, I was not aware.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Not necessarily, sometimes you learn De Morgan's equivalence via truth table and therefore you can use in a natural deduction as a proof to prove it. However, I see your point. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have derived $P$ and $Q$ from $P\land Q$, so further assuming $\lnot P$ or $\lnot Q$ leads to contradiction in both cases. $\lnot P\to\bot$ and $\lnot Q\to\bot$.

Then you may derive a contradiction from $P\land Q$ and $\lnot P\lor\lnot Q$ by eliminating the disjunction.

Introduce the negation and you are done; $\lnot (\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)$ is derived from $P\land Q$.

---

Conversely, from a premise of $\lnot (\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)$, a contradiction may be derived assumption of $\lnot P$ or of $\lnot Q$. After either, just introduce a disjunction to derive $\lnot P\lor\lnot Q$, then eliminate the negation.

So make those assumptions, derive those contradictions, so as to introduce two negations, eliminated the double negations that result, and finally introduce a conjunction to thusly derive $P\land Q$ from $\lnot(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I have not yet learned how to prove with contradiction i.e. what we need to make use of are either conjunction Intro and Elimination, disjunction Intro and Elimination, implication Intro and Elimination, bi implication Intro and Elimination, negation Intro and Elimination.
Is there a way this can be solved like this?

Comment: Negation Introduction *is* that if a contradiction is derived from an assumption of $p$, then the assumption may be discharged to deduce $\lnot p$.$$\begin{array}{|l}\vdots\\\quad\begin{array}{|l} p\\\hline\vdots\\\bot\end{array}\\\lnot p\end{array}$$

Comment: Negation Elimination *is* that if two contrary statements are derived within a context, then contradiction may also be dervied. $$\begin{array}{|l}p\\\lnot p\\\hline\bot\end{array}$$

Comment: Or are you using those names for completely different rules?

Comment: ... Well some authors do avoid the contradiction symbol and use *negation elimination* as: $$\begin{array}{|l}\quad \begin{array}{|l} p \\\hline q\end{array}\\\quad\begin{array}{|l} p\\\hline \lnot q\end{array}\\\lnot p \end{array}$$They might pair it with *ex falso quodlibet*.$$\begin{array}{|l} p\land\lnot p\\\hline q\end{array}$$

Comment: Hi @GrahamKemp thanks for your answer and replies! I use the second to last method for negation elimination however if this was an examable question we can't use any lemmas i.e. p^¬p entails q. We have to basically use the basics of the basics

Comment: Well, *ex falso quodlibet*, aka the principle of explosion, is considered a fundamental rule of inference in most natural deduction systems. @DavidVella (excepting minimal logic proofs)

Answer (score 0):

A different way of looking at it involves using a truth table :

[image]